# Windows 8 App iframe trying access page content on intranet

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, winjs, intranet

I am building a Windows 8 App for my company using JavaScript and HTML.  I have an iframe that loads a company webpage but gets "Access Denied" when trying to access the iframes contentDocument property.  The iframe displays the page but I can't access it's properties (like history).   Both the app and webpage are internal to the company on the same network.  I read that the "Access Denied" error occurs when the iframe parent page is on a different domain as the page within the iframe.

1. How can I get the app's iframe to access the contentDocument since it does not run on a web server?
2. Is there way to set the app to the same domain as the webpage?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish, maybe there is another way? Can the information be communicated across the boundaries via postMessage?

Comment: I currently have an app that does allot of company task.  There are links to company sites within the app and we don't want to launch IE to view them.  Since two apps can't exist on two different monitors, IE puts the app in the background, which we do not want.  This is why we used the iframe.  The problem we are running into is that when you are navigating in the iframe, the back button in the app is not tracking those pages and users that have navigated to the site inside the iframe, can't go back one page.  I want to track those pages and add them to the apps back button or one I create.

Comment: I don't have control of the company's website so I don't see how I could get postMessage to work.  Wouldn't code to listen for my message so it can send info back be required on the webpages?  There are many pages the users can navigate to through the app.

Comment: One option(hack) although it would take a little fiddling is when the page is navigated to an external link, actually navigate to an included page with an iframe. That page is sent the URL to load into the iframe. So the navigation is actually going to a conter host page. I you want your users to navigate several levels deep from the external page and have the back button work all along the way, this technique won't work- when the back button is pressed the entire iframe host page would disappear and go back to your apps prior internal page.

Comment: Unfortunately, they would be going levels deep.

Comment: You may be able to run a host page then form your domain - give that host page access to winjs, and in turn let it access its inner frame. That may work for you. so - main page in local context hosts an iframe on your domain. That iframe url has been given access to local winjs, and in turn hosts another iframe in it that is used for nav. That _may_ work :)

Comment: Can you give more details how this would be done?

Comment: Lets talk a bit more in depth about this before posting a solution here, grab a session at ohours.org/adamtuliper or email me adamt (then microsoft)

Comment: Unfortunately all Windows 8 LOB Development have been placed on hold due to multiple issues.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you can email me outlining those issues, it may help us in the future in providing a better experience.

Comment: For when this is revisited, check out the WebView control in 8.1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182879.aspx#webview

Answer (score 2):

Your local application will always run in a different context (called the local context). HTML content on the web would be in the web context.

See here for more context information on what is/is not allowed:
[Features and restrictions by context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465373.aspx)

I'm not aware of a way to set the same domain but you can try the techniques listed here under 'To give a web page additional access'. I haven't tried that in your scenario though personally.

[How to link to external web pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780594.aspx)

Communication between contexts generally takes places via the postMessage function as described here:[Developing Secure Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh849625.aspx)

I would see if the information you want can be communicated via postMessage.